# Executing query in chunks on Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I am trying to creating a way to convert bulk date queries into incremental query. For example, if a query has where condition specified as

```
WHERE date > now()::date - interval '365 days' and date < now()::date
```

this will fetch a years data if executed today. Now if the same query is executed tomorrow, 365 days data will again be fetched. However, I already have last 364 days data from previous run. I just want a single day's data to be fetched and a single day's data to be deleted from the system, so that I end up with 365 days data with better performance. This data is to be stored in a separate temp table.

To achieve this, I create an incremental query, which will be executed in next run. However, deleting the single date data is proving tricky when that "date" column does not feature in the SELECT clause but feature in the WHERE condition as the temp table schema will not have the "date" column.

So I thought of executing the bulk query in chunks and assign an ID to that chunk. This way, I can delete a chunk and add a chunk and other data remains unaffected.

Is there a way to achieve the same in postgres or greenplum? Like some inbuilt functionality. I went through the whole documentation but could not find any.

Also, if not, is there any better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best handled with something like an aggregates table (I assume the issue is you have heavy aggregates to handle over a lot of data).  This doesn't necessarily cause normalization problems (and data warehouses often denormalize anyway).  In this regard the aggregates you need can be stored per day so you are able to cut down to one record per day of the closed data, plus non-closed data.  Keeping the aggregates to data which cannot change is what is required to avoid the normal insert/update anomilies that normalization prevents.